# Android If statement for multiple setOnClickListener

Tags: java, android, imageview

I have multiple setOnClickListener and what I want to do is, to make it more simple.

Here's my java

```
 @Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    // get the button view
    ImageView foodImg = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.iconFoods);
    ImageView barsImg = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.iconBars);
    ImageView roomsImg = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.iconRooms);
    ImageView wellnessImg = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.iconWellness);
    ImageView beachesImg = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.iconBeaches);
    ImageView kidsImg = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.iconKids);
    ImageView attractionsImg = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.iconAttractions);
    ImageView shopsImg = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.iconShops);
    ImageView museumsUmg = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.iconMuseum);

    // set a onclick listener for when the food button gets clicked
    foodImg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        // Start new list activity
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),
                    Food.class);
            startActivity(mainIntent);
        }
    });

    // set a onclick listener for when the bars button gets clicked
    barsImg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),
                    Bars.class);
            startActivity(mainIntent);
        }
    });
```

As you can see I create one setOnClickListener for each ImageView.
My Question is, how to use if statement for multiple setOnClickListener?
So when I click ImageView Foods Icon I open the foods activity.
Thanks before :D

Comment: Read at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html#EventListeners

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a common onClickListener

```
    private OnClickListener onClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            switch(v.getId()){
                case R.id.button1:
                    ((TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText("Button 1 pushed");
                    break;
                case R.id.button2:
                    ((TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText("Button 2 pushed");
                    break;
                case R.id.button3:
                    ((TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText("Button 3 pushed");
                    break;
              }
        }
    };
```

Then set each View to use that click listener, i.e:

```
        Button btn1 = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button btn2 = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Button btn3 = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.button3);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        btn3.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Used **Switch Case** for that in `onClick(...)` like

```
   public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.iconFoods:
              //do your Intent
            break;

        case R.id.iconBars:
              //do your Intent
            break;

        case R.id.iconRooms:

            break;

        case R.id.iconWellness:
            //do your Intent
            break;

        case R.id.iconBeaches:
             //do your Intent
            break;

        and so on....
    }
}
```

But for this your `Activity` or `Fragment` must extends `onClickListener` Interface

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
```

and you'll set this `Listener` to your `ImageView` like:

```
foodImg.setonClickListner(this); 
roomsImg.setonClickListner(this);
...and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign the same listener to all of the views.

```
foodImg.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Then implement the listener interface in your Fragment.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
```

and add the `onClick()` method to your Fragment:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.iconBars:
            // handle the click
            break;

        case R.id.iconMuseum:
            // handle the click
            break;

        // add all the other cases here

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement OnClickListener to your activity , just like this:-

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
```

After Implementing it will ask you to add umimplemented method, then on that method you can use switch case just like following

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.foodImg :

        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    }
```

And dont forget to assign the same listener to all of the views.

For that you can make an method and call it on the OnCreate method

```
     private void registrerListeners() {
                foodImg.setOnClickListener(this);
//rly add rest oncliclisterner of your image
            }
```